# How to use different date formats (for displaying on html and storing in database) in JQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to display following date format on my web-page: 

`dd MM, yy` (like this `23 September, 2015`)

Therefore I included following JavaScript

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd MM, yy' });
```

But MySQL database accepts following date format to execute queries:

`yy-mm-dd` (like this `2015-09-23`)

In following code, I am trying to store MySQL's desired format in a variable to pass it to PHP by ajax call

```
var history_date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
```

But variable `history_date` is returned with web-page display format like `23 September, 2015` (which is not suitable for MySQL queries).

Please give me some solution to access two different date formats for display and database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would normally use an [alternate field](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field). So you can choose a format for your frontend to display, but have another value to send via ajax, which suites your needs.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'd MM, yy',
  altField: "#alternate",
  altFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
```

You then can take the date from your `#alternate` dom object. This can be a hidden input field.

```
<input type="hidden" id="alternate">
```

Getting the value for your ajax call works as expected.

```
var history_date = $('#alternate').val();
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to format the date you get back from your datepicker. Otherwise just grab the date and format your self appropriately.

```
var history_date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).getDate()
var day = history_date.getDate();
var monthIndex = history_date.getMonth()+1;
var year = history_date.getFullYear();
var date_formatted = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
```